# Can't protect internal api using IdentityServer 4 (500 error)

Tags: c#, asp.net, identityserver4

A bit of background, I have an IdenityServer 4 project that I use to protect access to an mvc project that I have (Using ASP.NET Identity).

Now what I also wanted was an api that is protected via client credentials that returns some information.

What I did was make a new core api project and this was working fine with the client protection, however, I wanted to move the api so it was within IdenityServer.

e.g. localhost:5000/api/info/getinfo

Now I have moved the code over I get a 500 error when I use the attribute [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "Bearer")]

I can use the DiscoveryClient to get a successful token using the credentials but can't with any request unless they are not authorized.

So in ID I set up my start up like this:

```
        services.AddMvc();

        services.AddMvcCore()
            .AddAuthorization()
            .AddJsonFormatters();

        // Configure identity server with in-memory stores, keys, clients and scopes
        services.AddIdentityServer()
            .AddDeveloperSigningCredential()
            .AddInMemoryPersistedGrants()
            .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(Config.GetIdentityResources())
            .AddInMemoryClients(Config.GetClients(Configuration))
            .AddInMemoryApiResources(Config.GetApiResources())
            .AddAspNetIdentity<ApplicationUser>();

        services.AddAuthentication("Bearer")
            .AddIdentityServerAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.Authority = Configuration.GetSection("Authority").Value;
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;

                options.ApiName = "IdentityInfoApi";
            });
```

And then for my api call that is protected I tag it with: [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "Bearer")]

but this returns me a 500 error, now when I use the tag: [Authorize] it works but that's because the user is logged into the mvc app and the response is an html page and not the json object i want.

At the moment I'm using a unit test to hit the api and the code looks like this:

```
var client = new HttpClient();

        var disco = DiscoveryClient.GetAsync("https://localhost:5000").Result;

        var tokenClient = new TokenClient(disco.TokenEndpoint, "client", "secret");
        var tokenResponse = tokenClient.RequestClientCredentialsAsync("IdentityInfoApi").Result;
        client.SetBearerToken(tokenResponse.AccessToken);

        var response = client.GetAsync("https://localhost:5000/api/info/getinfo").Result;
        if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var userResult = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

            var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PagedUserList>(userResult);

            Assert.NotNull(result);
        }
```

Is there something wrong with my setup of ID, the client code or can you not use ID in this way?

Thank's for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot of playing around I believe I found the fix.

You must define AddAuthentication() before AddIdentity() or in other words you must configure the api before Identity Server

It's fine to do it any way round if your api is external but not if it is within the Identity Server app it'self.

My new code looks like this:

```
  //Configure api
        services.AddMvcCore()
            .AddAuthorization()
            .AddJsonFormatters();

        services.AddAuthentication("Bearer")
            .AddIdentityServerAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.Authority = "https://localhost:5000";
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;

                options.ApiName = "IdentityInfoApi";
            });
        //end

        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(config =>
        {
            config.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = true;
        })
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        // Add application services.
        services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, EmailSender>();
        services.Configure<AuthMessageSenderOptions>(Configuration.GetSection("SMTP"));

        services.AddMvc();

        // Configure identity server with in-memory stores, keys, clients and scopes
        services.AddIdentityServer()
            .AddDeveloperSigningCredential()
            .AddInMemoryPersistedGrants()
            .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(Config.GetIdentityResources())
            .AddInMemoryClients(Config.GetClients(Configuration))
            .AddInMemoryApiResources(Config.GetApiResources())
            .AddAspNetIdentity<ApplicationUser>();
```

Hope this helps anyone else

Comment: worked for me thanks. could you fix a typo in 'localhost'? I copied the code and passed 10 minutes figuring out it was giving 500!